# (node:20732) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I am trying to generate confirmation link in my application. although it works fine and generate links too but when i visit that link it says in chrome console

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/confirmation 400 (Bad Request)
```

and terminal gives this error

```
(node:20732) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depr
ecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate th
e Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:20732) DeprecationWarning: collection.findAndModify is deprecated. Use fin
dOneAndUpdate, findOneAndReplace or findOneAndDelete instead.
```

> this is my router file router/auth

```
router.post('/confirmation', (req, res) => {
  const {token} = req.body.token;
  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    {confirmationToken: token},
    {confirmation: '', confirmed: true},
    {new: true}
).then(user => user ? res.json({user: user.toAuthJSON() }) : res.status(400).json({}));
});
```

how can i solve this issue. is this because of promise handler or some other issue with nodejs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to handle issue of an unhandled promise rejection you can call `.catch()` on the promise and handle the rejection.

```
router.post('/confirmation', (req, res) => {
  const {token} = req.body.token;
  User
  .findOneAndUpdate(
    {confirmationToken: token},
    {confirmation: '', confirmed: true},
    {new: true})
  .then(user => res.json({user: user.toAuthJSON() }))
  .catch(err => res.status(501).send("User- query promise was rejected. Handle according to specific case."));
});
```

Comment: thanks this removed the unhandled promise rejection warning

Comment: This does not suppress the warning. It resolves the underlying issue by handling the promise rejection.