# 504 on Node.JS frontend Azure AppService calling C# API backend Azure AppService

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

We have a frontend using ExpressJS server and talk to a backend on .NET 5. Both frontend and backend are running on separate Azure AppService.

```
FE: https://my-front-end.azurewebsites.net

BE: https://my-back-end.azurewebsites.net
```

Whenever we try to call the backend from frontend, it will always return 504 Gateway Timeout.

We try to add a simple `/hello` endpoint on the FE side and we could see `{"message":"Hello World!"}` is printed out. But the other endpoints, for example `api/vessels/3` will get `504 - Gateway Timeout`

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// import path from 'path';

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 1337; // default port to listen

app.use(cors());
app.use(function(_, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With');
  next();
});
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(process.cwd() + '/ui/build/'));

// define a route handler for the default home page
app.get('/', (_, res) => {
  res.sendFile(process.cwd() + '/ui/build/index.html');
});

app.get('/hello', (_, res) => {
  res.status(200).send({ message: "Hello World!" });
});

const getHeaders = (domain = 'ABC') => {
  return {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'cp-site-domain': domain
  }
};

const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.API_API_URL,
  timeout: process.env.REQUEST_TIMEOUT
});

app.get('/api/vessels/:orgId', async (req, res) => {
  const { orgId } = req.params;
  const { data } = await http.get(`/Vessels?organizationId=${orgId}`, {
    headers: getHeaders()
  });

  res.status(200).send(data);
});

// start the Express server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server started at http://localhost:${ port }`);
});
```

The error log from `iisnode` is:

```
(node:9880) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect EACCES 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16)
    at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:130:17)
(node:9880) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:9880) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

There is no problem if the backend APIs are being called directly from the UI (the usual AJAX). The error only happen when the request to BE is being triggered by ExpressJS.

Do we need to configure something on NodeJS or on Azure AppService side?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(node:20732) \[DEP0018\] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52089945/node20732-dep0018-deprecationwarning-unhandled-promise-rejections-are-depr)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT I read that link before and it's only showing how to catch the exception. My question is why NodeJS can't call the backend service.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem.

It turns out, the problem is related to the environment variable. On the local development, we are using `dotenv` that loads environment variables from a `.env` file into `process.env`.

The value of the environment variables are not loaded when we deploy the NodeJS into Azure AppService.

So, we need to add the environment variables into the AppService > Configuration and restart the app.